# List of services running on the machine using Node js

Tags: node.js

I want to write a program in node js that gets the list of services running on the machine and find their status. Is there any command or api in node js that gives the list of services running on the machine.
I tried running the sc query command from node

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec;
exec("sc query state= all", function(err, stdout) {
var lines = stdout.toString().split("\r\n").filter(function (line) {
    return line.indexOf("SERVICE_NAME") !== -1;
}).map(function (line) {
    return line.replace("SERVICE_NAME: ", "");
});
console.log(lines);
```

});

This gave me an array of the services running......How do I modify it to get a 2 dimensional array to get the name of the service and the state of the service

Comment: thank you for your answers.... I tried   var exec = require("child_process").exec;
exec("sc query state= all", function(err, stdout) {
    var lines = stdout.toString().split("\r\n").filter(function (line) {
        return line.indexOf("SERVICE_NAME") !== -1;
    }).map(function (line) {
        return line.replace("SERVICE_NAME: ", "");
    });
    console.log(lines);
});..................This runs the sc query and gives an array of the services running.................is this a good approach?

Answer (score 0):

There is a NPM module called "windows-service-controller" for this purpose. Here is the documentation [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-service-controller).

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how the services are started and what is the operating system.

Some services may be started e.g. with PM2 - for that you can use the programatic API of PM2:

- http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-api/#programmatic-api

Some other services can be started by init scripts, Upstart, systemd or any other way. Search npm for a module that works with your particular service starter and work with that.

For example if you use Upstart:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/upstart
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/upstarter

Since you didn't include in your question any information of what operating system and what way to start the services you're using, it's hard to give you a more detailed answer.